# Why does this simple JavaScript password regex not work?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am building a password checker - I have a simple requirement for at least three lowercase non-consecutive letters for now and either I have a large misunderstanding of regexes, or something else.

I have written the following code:

```
var password = 'mYpAsSwOrD',
    r = new RegExp('[a-z]{3,}', 'g');

console.log(password.match(r)); // null
console.log(r.test(password)); // false
```

Also, is the 'g' flag needed? Does the quantifier not provide the same functionality effectively?

What is the better comparison? Matching the regex against the string (first example); or testing the string against the regex (second example)?

Comment: `requirement for at least three lowercase letters`. Can you please explain this part more?

Comment: `[a-z]{3,}` will not match capitol letter or numbers os specail characters.Is this a requirement?

Comment: your current regex is currently checking for at least 3 *consecutive* lowercase letters.

Comment: Thanks Jerry - any idea how I can enhance it so it looks for three characters, non-consecutive?

Comment: @keldar Maybe easiest way would be to replace all characters that are not lowercase letters and get the string length of the resulting string.

Comment: Sorry - I confused some of you - the requirement is three, lowercase non-consecutive letters (i.e. the password must have >= 3 lowercase letters throughout the password).

Answer (score 2):

It matches only the strings which has atleast 3 lowercase letters.

```
> /^(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3}/.test("mYpAsSwOrD")
true
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `(?..)` Called non-capturing groups, which won't capture any characters but would do only matching operation.
- `[^a-z]*` this would match any character zero or more times.
- `[a-z]` this would match a lowercase letter.
- `(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3}` So if the whole non-capturing group is repeated three times, it could match the strings with atleast three lowercase letters. For testing purposes only , we don't need to go for a full match.

**OR**

You could try the below positive lookahead.

```
^(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3})
```

**Code:**

```
> /^(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3})/.test("mYpAsSwOrD")
true
```

Comment: Thanks - could you expand on how this works a little? Particularly, the '?:' syntax?

Comment: @Jonny5 yep the first one take 13 steps to finish whether the second lookahead takes 15 steps to finish.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=(.*?[a-z]){3}).*
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/24

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Could you explain/expand your answer just to describe the syntax - I haven't come across the ?= syntax before

Comment: @keldar it called positive lookahead.it looks for the condition of `3 small letters` ahead.

Comment: Oh yeah, makes sense now :) - I don't think '.*' is needed at the end, because of the positive lookahead provides the same functionality (or have I misunderstood).

Comment: @keldar .* is needed to consume the strings...... lookahead does not consume string

Answer (score 0):

Your original regex matches where the three desired characters are consecutive. You can change the regex to this:

```
r = /[a-z](?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2}/;
```

- `[a-z]` Matches a lowercase character.
- `(?:[^a-z]*[a-z])` Skips over all non-lowercase characters and attempts to match a lowercase character.
- - `{2}` Two times.

As for your other question, the `g` flag is not necessary as it allows repeat matches, while for your use case you're simply matching the first collection and asserting true for return.